# Pandas: Using rolling_mean() with maximum information criteria as a Smoothing Function?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use pd.rolling_mean() as a smoothing function keeping the maximum information criteria. This means the endpoints are computed differently depending on the information available. An example of a window=3, center=True is below:

```
For Example: Window = 3, Center = True
ts_smooth[0] = 1/2 * ts[0] + 1/2 * ts[1]
ts_smooth[0<n<N-1] = 1/3 * ts[n-1] + 1/3 * ts[n] + 1/3 * ts[n+1]
ts_smooth[N] = 1/2 * ts[N-1] + 1/2 * ts[N]
```

What is the best way to achieve this in Pandas?

1. Compute rolling_mean() for midpoints
2. Write a function to replace the end conditions based on window size?

Comment: The keyword argument ``min_periods`` may be relavant. ``pd.rolling_mean(np.arange(5), 3, center=True, min_periods=0)`` gives ``[ 0.5,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  nan]``. On the right track.

Comment: Mysteriously, _any_ value passed to ``min_periods`` changes the first element of the result from ``nan`` to ``0``. That may be a bug.

Comment: Without setting centre as True, for any i-th element, if first collect elements in the periods [i-2, i-1, i], if the number of elements found in these periods is smaller than min_periods, than it returns nan. While you set min_periods as 1, it only collect the element 0, so it returns the mean 0. Once you set min_periods more than 1, it'll return nan since you only collect 1 element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the shift function, like so,

```
ts_shiftedPlus = ts.shift(1)
ts_shiftedMinus = ts.shift(-1)

ts_smooth = 1/3 * ts_shiftedMinus + 1/3 * ts + 1/3 * ts_shiftedPlus
ts_smooth.ix[0] = 1/2 * ts.ix[0] + 1/2 * ts.ix[1]
N = len(ts)
ts_smooth.ix[N] = 1/2 * ts.ix[N-1] + 1/2 * ts.ix[N]
```

Comment: This works well ... for endpoints. However, if there is missing data within the series - that takes a bit more work. I will work on a function for this.