# Pandas rolling_mean with center keyword leaves last values as NaN

Tags: pandas

I noticed behaviour in pandas rolling_mean function I did not expect.

If we execute:

```
ser = pd.Series(np.arange(5),index=pd.date_range(start=datetime(2007,1,1),end=datetime(2007,1,5)))
>>> ser
2007-01-01    0
2007-01-02    1
2007-01-03    2
2007-01-04    3
2007-01-05    4
Freq: D, dtype: int64

>>> avg = pd.rolling_mean(ser,window=3,min_periods=1,center=True)
>>> avg
2007-01-01    0.5
2007-01-02    1.0
2007-01-03    2.0
2007-01-04    3.0
2007-01-05    NaN
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

I would expect the last value to be 3.5 as in (3+4)/2 which would be consistent with the first value in the series.

Is this a bug or a feature? I am aware that "financial" rolling means and "scientific" rolling means are different but I think this should produce a series without NaN values.

Cheers,
Christoph

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214248/pandas-using-rolling-mean-with-maximum-information-criteria-as-a-smoothing-fu

Comment: With the parameters as given I would expect to have both the 1st and last values to be NaNs or the last value as you described